# php json_encode UTF-8

Tags: php, unicode, json

php maual of `json_encode()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php says:
All string data of the first input parameter value must be UTF-8 encoded.

Does it really mean that the string data MUST NOT contain any `0x00 byte` (in unicode it may appear)?

I know it will be OK if the input parameter is a valid string encoded in utf-8 . But what about if the input string is a valid GBK-encoded string? Guys, do you know anything about GBK and what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

It means that data must be valid UTF-8. utf8encode function converts ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, so if you already have that, no need to double-encode it.

[A comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php#104906) on [utf8_encode manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) which I believe to be correct:

> utf8_encode only converts a string encoded in ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. A
>   more appropriate name for it would be "iso88591_to_utf8". If your text
>   is not encoded in  ISO-8859-1, you do not need this function. If your
>   text is already in UTF-8, you do not need this function. In fact,
>   applying this function to text that is not encoded in ISO-8859-1 will
>   most likely simply garble that text.

So the answer to your question is no, it doesn't mean that. Vice versa. If it is valid UTF-8, then it is ok.

Comment: Hey, I wrote that comment!

Comment: @deceze so it seems :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it means the string must be valid UTF-8. `0x00` is Unicode character U+0000 and encoded as `0x00` in UTF-8.

```
php > var_dump(json_encode(["\x00"]));
string(10) "["\u0000"]"
```